# Bulkcopy data from Oracle to SQL Server : String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: sql-server, oracle, c#-4.0

I am trying to copy data from Oracle to SQL Server using `bulkcopy`. The problem is that Oracle's boolean data is stored as `varchar2(1)` as `t` and `f` while SQL Server boolean data type is `bit` and stored as `1` and `0`. Therefore I got the following error.

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type bit of the specified target column.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type bit of the specified target column.
>   System.FormatException: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean.
>   System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
using (OracleConnection srcConn = new OracleConnection())
using (SqlConnection destConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    srcConn.ConnectionString = AppInfo.SrcConnStr;
    srcConn.Open();
    destConn.ConnectionString = AppInfo.DestConnStr;
    destConn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand destCmd = new SqlCommand("SET DATEFORMAT mdy;", destConn))
    using (OracleCommand srcCmd = new OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'", srcConn))
    {
        srcCmd.CommandText = "select * from test";
        rd = srcCmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(destConn);
        // ColumnMappings property is used to map column positions, not data type
        copy.DestinationTableName = "test";
        copy.NotifyAfter = 2000;
        copy.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsCopied);
        copy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000000;
        try { copy.WriteToServer((IDataReader)rd); }
        TargetCount = (Int32)(typeof(SqlBulkCopy).GetField("_rowsCopied", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance)).GetValue(copy);
        copy.Close();
        rd.Close();
    }
}
```

Note that I have cast the `SqlDataReader` to `IDataReader` in a hope that the cast will convert T to 1 and F to 0. Obviously it is not.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try to changed the value type before get data . like :

```
select case when id='T' then 1 else 0 end as id from test
```

id is the column that has different datatype between oracle and sqlserver.

Comment: This is one way to do it. However, we got hundreads of tables and tens of such columns in each table. and our tables are changing all the time. If there any way to let .NET to handle it?

Comment: have to go this way. Thanks:)